# how to apply gaussian filter correctly

Tags: c++, canny-operator, stb-image

Im currently try to make Canny edge detection using stb_imahe and c++ without 3rfparty library
My code:

```
 // Generate gaussian kernel

 int size = 5, center = (size-1) / 2;

 float sigma = 1.4f;

 std::vector<std::vector<double>> kernel(size, std::vector<double>(size));

 double sum = 0.0;

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

 {

  for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)

  {

   int x=j-(center+1),y=i-(center+1);

   kernel[i][j]=(1.0/(2*M_PI*sigma*sigma))*exp(-(x*x+y*y)/(2*sigma*sigma));

   sum+=kernel[i][j];

  }

 }debug(kernel);

 // Normalize gausian kernel

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

 {

  for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)

  {

   kernel[i][j]/=sum;

  }

 } debug(kernel);



 // Apply gaussian filter to image

 std::vector<unsigned char> temp(size*channels);

 for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)

 {

  for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)

  {

   for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)

   {

    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

    {

     for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)

     {

      int neighbor_x = x + j - center;

      int neighbor_y = y + i - center;

      int clamped_x = std::min(std::max(neighbor_x, 0), width - 1);

      int clamped_y = std::min(std::max(neighbor_y, 0), height - 1);

      sum += kernel[i][j] * data[(clamped_y*width+clamped_x)*channels+c];

     }

    }

    temp[(y*width+x)*channels+c]=static_cast<unsigned char>(sum);

   }

  }

 }

 std::copy(temp.data(), temp.data()+size*channels, data);

 temp.clear();

 stbi_write_png("gaussian.png", width, height, channels, data, width*channels);
```

the picture i use from wikipedia rgb format from Canny edge detection

(in my code i copy to here is removing the grayscale conversion)

when i run in grayscale is normal but the gaussian is have problem it show the top part is likely true (apply blur) but the remaining is still normal and i swap some part for checking it wasnt apply blur

Please help me

Comment: if you found my code hard to read, please dont angry because when i paste code to here it very normal until i post it, it have a new line between line

Comment: You should [edit] your post and reduce the unneeded spaces (you are right that it makes the code hard to read).